# Android call log reading

Tags: android, calllog

Hello guys I am facing a problem when I read the CallLog the values of the number are 0 and when I read for example the cached name its 2 
here is my code and I put the permission

```
         String[] fields = {
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE
    };
String order = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"; 

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
    fields,
    null,
    null,
    order
    );

if(c.moveToFirst()){


  do{

//the problem was here                //System.out.println(c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)+" - - "); 

//the solution is :$
System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER))+" - - "); 

  } while (c.moveToNext());

}
```

and I have read all the related questions on stackoverflow 
I figured it out so I will keep the question if any one faced it I was dump :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on phone, also not all/any columns are required to be filled in. Up to carrier/manufacturer/whomever else wants to write to the table.  But yes the question fix would do it

Comment: Thanks for the information I am feeling sleepy so I should drink some coffee to avoid this awful mistake :$

Comment: Also, one thing i've noticed from using this table that may be useful is that negative numbers(-1 or -2) in the number column often mean they're from a private number

Comment: What I am trying to do is calculating the call duration on specific provider like the number starts with 001 between two dates 
would this be available on every android devices with different OS releases   ?

Comment: the phones I have all have the number, duration, and date so you should be ok with those.  However, the number format is based on either what you typed into the dialer(could be without area code or 1) or what the dialer saves for the calling number(could start with + could start with 1 depends) so you might want to come up with some way to normalize the number

Comment: Is there any way to discover additional columns a manufacturer may have provided?